# Socket.emit() and/or socket.on() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

I am making a game using node.js and socket.io and I just want to send a variable to the client using socket.emit() and socket.on(). However, this does not seem to work and I am not exactly sure why. I have made a condensed program to see if I am even writing this correctly, as I am very new to socket.io.

```js
//server

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var PLAYER_LIST = {};

var optypes = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]

var op1 = {
    x: 450,
    y: 600,
    type: optypes[0]
}
socket.emit('operations', op1);
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="900" height="1400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>

//client

var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';
    
    var socket = io();


    socket.on('operations', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        
    });

</script>
```

Is it the socket.emit? Is it the socket.on? Is it both? Why am I not receiving the variable op1 in the console?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: where did you inculuded `socket` in server?

Answer (score 0):

You should emit after the `connection`. Otherwise client is not going to receive it. Change your sever code with below

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(serv);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');
var SOCKET_LIST = {};
var PLAYER_LIST = {};
var optypes = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
var op1 = {
    x: 450,
    y: 600,
    type: optypes[0]
}
io.on('connection',(socket) =>{
    socket.emit('operations', op1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still does not seem to work. Correct me if I am wrong, but I would see op1 in the console almost as soon as I load it correct? If so, that is not what I see. The console is empty.

Comment: @LMM3804 then there should be a problem somewhere else in code. Try to comment out code and then check.

Comment: Well that is a separate program I made to make sure there was nothing wrong somewhere else in the code. I copied and pasted exactly what that is. That is something completely separate, and is not working. I just thought I'd isolate it to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @LMM3804 did you installed socket.io using `npm i --save socket.io`?

Comment: @LMM3804 can't say anything. Its working fine more me. Did you have this line in you server. `var io = require('socket.io')(serv);`. And make sure you have `index.html` on the path you have in server

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Line 4 is where I have the line you referenced. In my actual program, I have other socket.emit functions that work fine, however I used a tutorial to write them. When I wrote this one by myself, it did not work, and I've been trying all day to figure out why. I figured it had something to do with the way I was writing it. Anyway, thanks again for your help!

Comment: I mean thank you for your time. It did not completely solve my problem. My console is still empty. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @LMM3804 oh sorry. I thought it worked well good luck for your work and no need to accept if it didn't worked

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: www.section38.net:2000 is the address. You are welcome to take a look at it.

Comment: @LMM3804 The same code is working and logging perfectly fine for me. In my own node js project

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any socket io library in your server code. In order to emit a socket you have to wait until the connection to be established.

```
//server

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io')(serv);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var PLAYER_LIST = {};

var optypes = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]

var op1 = {
    x: 450,
    y: 600,
    type: optypes[0]
}

var connection = socketio
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('operations', op1);
});
```

Also you need to specify which server you are connecting to in your client code. If you are running your socket server on port 2000 you have to specify which server to connect to.

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="900" height="1400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>

//client

var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';

    var socket = io('http://localhost:2000');


    socket.on('operations', function(data) {
        console.log(data);        
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Again thank you for the suggestion, however the console is still empty.

Comment: Are you running the server from your local machine?

Comment: no I am running the server from a Windows 2012 VM Server. I did initially have the error of "localhost" on line 11, however changed that to my address and it ran fine with no errors, but no data either.

Comment: did you include the port? also check if your vm has the port opened.

Comment: yes the port is included. I copied and pasted the exact address from the address bar. Also, the vm does have the port opened.

Comment: i have the above code working on my local machine. getting the object in the console. it maybe your os or vm configuration. i don't think i can't be of help without more information

Comment: www.section38.net:2000 is the address. When I look in the console, there is nothing. You are more than welcome to take a look at it. The code is exactly copied and pasted as you wrote it with the small change of the localhost line.

Comment: i am looking at your html source. you've left io blank on line 11. since you did mention you've changed the address check if your static file is being served properly. i see ```var socket = io();``` in your html

Comment: I just changed it because I was trying Maheer Ali's code. I'll change it right back.

Comment: Okay I just changed it back. You should see www.section38.net:2000 in the socket variable